# ObjectListView Header BackColor

Tags: objectlistview

I have HeaderUsesThemes to false. When I 'edit columns' I can set the forecolor property of each header just fine but there is no property for the back color.

How can I set the back color of the Headers?

Comment: What have you already researched? What, in particular, isn't working for you?

Answer (score 9):

with ObjectListView, you can change the back color of Headers using the HeaderFormatStyle class.

Here is a short example (change all headers to the same style using  DarkBlue as Backcolor and Gray for text):

```
using System;
//...
using BrightIdeasSoftware;

//...

private void adjustMyObjectListViewHeader()
{
    foreach (OLVColumn item in olv.Columns)
        {
            var headerstyle =  new HeaderFormatStyle();
            headerstyle.SetBackColor(Color.DarkBlue);
            headerstyle.SetForeColor(Color.SlateGray);
            item.HeaderFormatStyle = headerstyle;
        }
}
```

olv is the ObjectListView Object

Details can be found in the ObjectListView Cookbook:
http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-change-the-font-or-color-of-the-column-headers

Hope this helps...